# Can Sage apply Chi Gong to a thrown ranged weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-power, spheres-of-might

I’m putting together a Votary Sage, making him kind of like a ninja. I want him able to toss shuriken as a ranged option, and intended to use Chi Gong through them by way of the Ki Weapon esotery.

Except, when I went back to look at it:
Ki Weapon [Cata. HB]

The sage gains the ability to channel the damage and other effects of chi gong through any **melee** weapon he is wielding rather than just unarmed or natural attacks. If the sage possesses the ki blaster esoteric training, he may apply the weapon’s enhancement bonus and any of its other special abilities (such as keen, flaming, or seeking) to the ki blast. **When applying bonuses to a ki blast, the sage may only transfer special abilities which could be applied to a ranged attack which deals the same type of damage as the ki blast.**

The former states melee weapon, while the latter specifies the ranged Chi Gong blast. What I want to know is, can I apply Chi Gong to a thrown weapon, and if so how would I go about achieving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't apply Ki Weapon to Shurikens.

They're listed as a ranged weapon, and thus are not a melee weapon.  You can potentially apply Ki Weapon to a weapon that is listed as a melee weapon but has a range increment, like the Throwing Axe.  I have not attempted to exhaustively search errata about this, but in the rules it does specify that a melee weapon that can be thrown is specifically a melee weapon, and not a ranged weapon.

You can get some throwing hatchets and apply Chi Gong to attacks with them, you can be a Ki Blaster and fluff your Dragonball style energy blasts as 'actually shurikens', or you can just ask your GM if you can apply chi gong to shurikens because they are short range weapons and chi gong isn't a lot of damage and you're taking a whole esotery for it.  It's not very powerful and absolutely fine to just houserule that to be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

When throwing shuriken, you are throwing manufactured weapons that target normal AC.

When using Ki Blaster (http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/sage#toc9), you are using a magical force as a melee touch attack or a ranged touch attack within close range.

Ki Weapon (http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/sage#toc19) is allowing you to apply the

> weapon enhancement bonus and any of its other special abilities (such as keen, flaming, or seeking)

of a manufactured weapon held to the ki blast.

Since shuriken are not considered melee weapon, you can't use them. But if you had a dagger that was +1 flaming, your destructive blast will be +1 to attack and damage with a 1d6 fire damage. There is a restriction that the special abilities cant be one that wont work with ranged touch attacks.

So your question

> can I apply Chi Gong to a thrown weapon, and if so how would I go about achieving it?

The answer is **no**, you are not throwing the weapon. You are just holding it and magically enhancing your blasting ability. Think of it as a amulet of mighty fists for ki blasts.